# Custom ajax promise function signature

Tags: javascript, ajax, es6-promise

I want to basically create a new function signature for ajax `done` and `fail` handlers...given the simplified example below, I'm just trying to append `resource` as the last parameter to be sent to the handler.

```
    const customAjax = function( url, resource ) {
        const p = $.ajax({
            converters: {
                'text script': function (text: string) {
                    return text;
                }
            },
            url: url + "?" + resource
        }).then(
            function () {
                [].push.apply(arguments, [resource]);
                return arguments;
            },
            function() {
                [].push.apply(arguments, [resource]);
                return arguments;
            }
        );

        return p;
    };
```

Then the preferred usage is something like:

```
customAjax( "url", "resourceKey" )
   .done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR, resourceName ) { /* do something */ } )
   .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, resourceName ) { /* do something */ } );
```

The problem is, in both handlers, there is only one parameter.  The javascript `arguments` object.  So, to access each parameter I really want, I have to do something like this instead:

```
customAjax( "url", "resourceKey" )
   .done( function( args ) { 
      var data = args[ 0 ];
      var textStatus = args[ 1 ];
      var jqXHR = args[ 2 ];
      var resourceName = args[ 3 ];
      /* do something */
   } )
   .fail( function( args ) { 
      var jqXHR = args[ 0 ];
      var textStatus = args[ 1 ];
      var errorThrown = args[ 2 ];
      var resourceName = args[ 3 ];
      /* do something */ 
} );
```

Is there any way to make it work the way I'd prefer?

**Update** - Not sure how to communicate with person that closed my question, but I don't see how the referenced 'duplicate' question answers/addresses my issue.

Comment: You'd have to overwrite the `fail` and `done` properties of the returned object. I would not go that way. Stick to the Promise interface, which has native support in JavaScript; that has more future than the specific jQuery interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to overwrite the `fail` and `done` method properties of the object that `$.ajax` returns, so to make sure that the callback that is eventually passed to these two methods is then called with the extra argument:

```
const customAjax = function( url, resource ) {
    const p = $.ajax({
        converters: {
            'text script': function (text: string) {
                return text;
            }
        },
        url: url + "?" + resource
    });
    let result = {
        ...p,
        done(f) {
            p.done(function (...args) {
                f.call(this, ...args, resource);
            });
            return result;
        },
        fail(f) {
            p.fail(function (...args) {
                f.call(this, ...args, resource);
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
    return result;
};
```

Demo:

```js
const customAjax = function( url, resource ) {
    const p = $.ajax({
        converters: {
            'text script': function (text) {
                return text;
            }
        },
        url: url + "?" + resource
    });
    let result = {
        ...p,
        done(f) {
            p.done(function (...args) {
                f.call(this, ...args, resource);
            });
            return result;
        },
        fail(f) {
            p.fail(function (...args) {
                f.call(this, ...args, resource);
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
    return result;
};


customAjax( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", "resourceKey" )
    .done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR, resourceName ) { 
        console.log( {data, textStatus, jqXHR, resourceName});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm...I never enter the `done(f)` or `fail(f)` handlers with this code.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then. I added a demo to my answer. When I run it, the `done` method is run with the extra argument.

Comment: It was tricky to get it to work in TS (just didn't know all the argument types at first).  JS can still be mind bending to me, lol.

Comment: Another tricky one for you if you are up for it ;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/66212471/166231

Comment: If I wanted to only use the `then()` instead of the obsolete `done` and `fail`, how would that be done?

Comment: If you have a new question, and you cannot make it work, then please post it as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481036/custom-ajax-then-signature